# Send values from inputs in react (change querySelector(id) to react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to rewrite a small app from vanilla js to react, and in one element I encountered a problem with passing on values in the inputs. What this element does, is after selecting a number it generates that many inputs to fill, and after filling send its id and value further (value can also be empty)
In Vanilla Js I did it with id and querySelector, but in React I have a trouble to change it correct

React code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import Values from "./Values";

export default function App() {
  const [numberValue, setNumberValue] = useState("");
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState([]);
  const [sendValues, setSendValues] = useState(false);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);
  let numbers = [4, 6, 8];

  //reset teamsName on change teamsValue
  useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberValue; i++) {
      setInputValues(prev => [
        ...prev,
        {
          id: i,
          value: ""
        }
      ]);
    }
  }, [numberValue]);

  const showButtons = numbers.map((number, i) => (
    <button
      className={`${numberValue === number ? "button active" : "button"}`}
      onClick={() => {
        setNumberValue(number);
        setInputValues([]);
        setInputs([]);
        showInputs();
      }}
    >
      {number}
    </button>
  ));
  //let inputs = [];
  const showInputs = () => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberValue; i++) {
      setInputs(prev => [
        ...prev,
        <input
          type="text"
          className="input"
          placeholder={`Input ${i}`}
          //value={inputValues.find(input => input.id === i && input.value)}
          onChange={e =>
            inputValues.filter(
              input =>
                input.id === i &&
                setInputValues([
                  ...inputValues,
                  { id: i, value: e.target.value }
                ])
            )
          }
        />
      ]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="button-group">{showButtons}</div>
      {numberValue && (
        <>
          <h3 className="title">Your inputs</h3>
          <div className="input-group">{inputs}</div>
        </>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => setSendValues(true)}>SEND</button>
      {sendValues && <Values inputValues={inputValues} />}
    </>
  );
}
```

JS:

```
const buttonGroup = document.querySelector(".button-group");
const inputGroup = document.querySelector(".input-group");
const inputValues = document.querySelector(".input-values");
let n;
const showInputs = number => {
  n = number;
  inputGroup.innerHTML = ''
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    inputGroup.innerHTML += `
      <input type="text" name="name" id="input-${i}" class="input" placeholder="team name"> <br>
    `;
  }
};
let values = []
const showValues = () => {
  //clear
  inputValues.innerHTML = '';
  values = [];
  //show new
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      const input_val = document.querySelector(`#input-${i}`).value;
      values.push({
        id: i,
        value: input_val
      });
    } 
  
  for(let i = 0; i<=n; i++){
      inputValues.innerHTML += `
  <p>id: ${values[i].id} value:${values[i].value}
  </p>
  `
  }

};
```

Links to code:
React -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uw9dzc?file=src/App.js
JS -> https://codepen.io/Arex/pen/qBqLVBq?editors=1111

Comment: What exactly the problem? The send button?

Comment: @SelvaS inputValues are not changing like they should. I want to have the same effect in React like in JS example so after filling all inputs I want to show their values in new component

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to simplify your code a bit. Basically I assigned value as it's own variable `const value = e.target.value;` as it is a synthetic event and tends to get lost if you pass it further down, so this preserves the value. Also, I changed `inputValues` to an object to make it easier to update:

```
// App.js
export default function App() {
  const [numberValue, setNumberValue] = useState("");
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({});
  const [sendValues, setSendValues] = useState(false);
  let numbers = [4, 6, 8];

  const showButtons = numbers.map((number, i) => (
    <button
      className={`${numberValue === number ? "button active" : "button"}`}
      onClick={async () => {
        await setNumberValue(number);
        await setInputValues({});
      }}
    >
      {number}
    </button>
  ));

  return (
    <>
      <div className="button-group">{showButtons}</div>
      {numberValue && (
        <>
          <h3 className="title">Your inputs</h3>
          <div className="input-group">
            {[...new Array(numberValue)].map((_value, id) => (
              <input
                type="text"
                className="input"
                placeholder={`Input ${id}`}
                onChange={e => {
                  const value = e.target.value;

                  setInputValues(prev => {
                    prev[id] = value;
                    return prev;
                  });
                }}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => setSendValues(true)}>SEND</button>
      {sendValues && <Values inputValues={inputValues} />}
    </>
  );
}

// Values.js
const Values = ({ inputValues }) => {
  const showValues = Object.keys(inputValues).map(input => (
    <div>
      {input} : {inputValues[input]}
    </div>
  ));
  return <div>{showValues}</div>;
};

export default Values;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in the shared code as follows:

1. It is not recommended to store components in state, in the shared code you are storing `<input/>` component in state. For more details check [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html)
2. Unnecessary states are being used, always try to keep a minimum number of states as more number of states as more states are needed to be managed, making things unnecesarily complicated.
3. using previous state syntax to generate new state where it is not needed.

I am adding a working code with minimum changes for you reference.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import Values from "./Values";

export default function App() {
    const [numberValue, setNumberValue] = useState('');
    const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState([]);
    const [sendValues, setSendValues] = useState(false);
    let numbers = [4, 6, 8];

    //reset teamsName on change teamsValue
    useEffect(() => {
        setInputValues(
            Array(numberValue).fill("")
        );
        setSendValues(false)
    }, [numberValue]);

    const showButtons = numbers.map((number, i) => (
        <button
            className={`${numberValue === number ? "button active" : "button"}`}
            onClick={() => {
                setNumberValue(number);
            }}
        >
            {number}
        </button>
    ));
    return (
        <>
            <div className="button-group">{showButtons}</div>
            {numberValue && (
                <>
                    <h3 className="title">Your inputs</h3>
                    <div className="input-group">
                        {inputValues.map((val, i) => (
                            <input
                                key={`input${i}`}
                                type="text"
                                className="input"
                                placeholder={`Input ${i+1}`}
                                value={val}
                                onChange={(e) => {let newValues = inputValues.slice(); newValues[i]=e.target.value; setInputValues(newValues)}
                                }
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
            <button onClick={() => setSendValues(true)}>SEND</button>
            {sendValues && <Values inputValues={inputValues} />}
        </>
    );
}
```

**Values.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Values = ({ inputValues }) => {
  const showValues = inputValues.map((input, i) => (
    <div key={'output'+i}>
      {i+1} : {input}
    </div>
  ));
  return <div>{showValues}</div>;
};

export default Values;
```

---

**I am also sharing a updated stackblitz code reference you shared for better understanding [Updated snippet with fixes for reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-81fj52?file=src/App.js).**